# Spyder Help Pane: Clickable icon and/or hot keys for zooming?

Tags: spyder

According to the [Online Help](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/onlinehelp.html), there should be magnifying glass icons with `+`/`-` signs for zooming in/out.  I do not have these

[image: Spyder GUI]

The normal hot keys [`Ctrl`+`+`/`=` and `Ctrl`+`-`](http://e-callisto.org/cospar2018/SpyderKeyboardShortcutsEditor.pdf) also do not work.

I have to go into `Tools > Preferences > Appearance` to set font sizes.  This is not convenient.

Why do `Ctrl`+`+`/`=` and `Ctrl`+`-` not work?

Is there a way to get the zoom icons onto the GUI?

Ultimately, I want to be able to zoom in on a whim to read small text, then zoom out on a whim to read the rest of the non-small text.  This is made necessary by aging eyes and the fact that the text font & size varies, not only across the GUI, but also within the same pane.  This is not obvious in the Help pane pictured above, but the text following the `Definition` section is bigger.  If I maximize the Spyder GUI window and maximize the Help pane, I am looking at both `Definition` text and the larger ensuing text.  It'd be great to zoom in and out on a per-pane basis, but zooming in/out on a whole-GUI basis would be better than not at all (or having to navigate to `Preferences`).

P.S. I am using Spyder 4.1.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please better describe what you want to achieve. Do you want to increase or decrease the font size in the entire interface? Or only in the Online Help? (which, by the way, is not shown in your screenshot).

Comment: @Carlos Corboda: Thanks for the prompt to clarify.  I've elaborated in the posted question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I verified that `Zoom in`/`Zoom out` are not working with `Ctrl++`/`Ctrl+-`. But you can access those actions by doing a mouse right click on the Help pane. However, those keyboard shortcuts work on other parts of our interface, such as the editor and the IPython console. Finally, there's no way to increase/decrease the font size of the entire interface, but we're planning to add an option to change the font in elements like tabs and menus in a future version. But that option won't work with `Ctrl++`/`Ctrl+-` because it's not easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos.  Did you want to post that as the answer?  I confirmed your right-click solution.

Comment: Done. And glad you found that solution useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> don't work to Zoom In/Out in our Help pane.

However, you can perform those actions by doing a mouse right-click on that pane to get its context menu and click on their corresponding entries, as shown below:

[image: Help's context menu]